# Proper way of creating a database with Mysql

Tags: javascript, mysql, backbone.js

I have a very basic question.  I am a student and I want to learn a proper way of creating a database with MySQL, like a DBA, starting from Entity diagram and what is the best tool to use, and then next step after the diagram and what tool is good to create a database. 
The front end is using Javascript, backbone, and Jquery mobile.
It would be great if someone can show me some direction as where to start and which way to go.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you tried mysql workbench, its very intuitive it allows you to define everything in an entity diagram and it will create the mysql code for you. its a free tool from mysql http://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/

Comment: its asking me 15 points reputation to upvote, I am still waiting to get it, I will upvote you when I reach that